# Discovering taxonomic relationships with Spacy

Tags: spacy

How can we make some generic inference of taxonomic relation between entities from text? Looking for words near 'type of' in the word2vec of en_core_web_lg model, they all seem unrelated. The words near 'type' however are more similar to it. But how can I use common phrases in my text and apply some generic similarity for inferring taxonomy from SVO triples etc.? Can do a Sense2Vec type approach, but wondering if something existing can be used without new training.

Output of code below:

```
['eradicate', 'wade', 'equator', 'educated', 'lcd', 'byproducts', 'two', 'propensity', 'rhinos', 'procrastinate']
```

```
 def get_related(word):
        filtered_words = [w for w in word.vocab if w.is_lower == word.is_lower and w.prob >= -15]
        similarity = sorted(filtered_words, key=lambda w: word.similarity(w), reverse=True)
        return similarity[:10]

print ([w.lower_ for w in get_related(nlp.vocab[u'type_of'])])
```

Answer (score 1):

All the similarities your code retrieves are `0.0`, so sorting the list has no effect.

You are treating "type_of" as a **word** (more accurately, a [lexeme](https://spacy.io/api/lexeme)), and assuming *spaCy* will understand it as the **phrase** "type of". Note that the first has an underscore, while the second one does not; however even without the underscore, it is not a lexeme in the model's vocabulary. Since the model does not have sufficient data on "type_of" for a similarity score, the score is `0.0` for every word you compare to it.

Instead, you can create a [`Span`](https://spacy.io/api/span) of the words "type of" and call `similarity()` on that. This requires only a small change to your code:

```python
import spacy


def get_related(span):  # this now expects a Span instead of a Lexeme

    filtered_words = [w for w in span.vocab if
                      w.is_lower == span.text.islower()
                      and w.prob >= -15]  # filter by probability and case
                                          # (use the lowercase words if and only if the whole Span is in lowercase)
    similarity = sorted(filtered_words,
                        key=lambda w: span.similarity(w),
                        reverse=True)  # sort by the similarity of each word to the whole Span
    return similarity[:10]  # return the 10 most similar words


nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')  # load the model

print([w.lower_ for w in get_related(nlp(u'type')[:])])  # print related words for "type"
print([w.lower_ for w in get_related(nlp(u'type of')[:])])  # print related words for "type of"
```

Output:

> ['type', 'types', 'kind', 'sort', 'specific', 'example', 'particular', 'similar', 'different', 'style']
>
> ['type', 'of', 'types', 'kind', 'particular', 'sort', 'different', 'such', 'same', 'associated']

As you can see, all the words are related to the input to some degree, and the output is similar but not identical for "type" and "type of".